# .htaccess 301 permanent redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this url structure right now.

```
http://example.com/weather/in-city_name
```

which I want to permanently redirect to

```
http://example.com/city_name/weather
```

Here is what I'm writing to the .htaccess file using [this reference](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/)

```
RedirectMatch ^/weather/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/weather
```

But this doesn't work.

In my condition **`city_name`** is dynamic and manual entry is not possible.

Any suggestion about how to achieve the desire result would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^weather/in-(.+)/?$ /$1/weather   [R=301,NC,L]
```